# RandomVariate from Multiplying distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

Mathematica's `RandomVariate` works fine with the `KernelMixtureDistribution[]` function, but it doesn't seem to work if you wish to generate random numbers from a product of `KernelMixtureDistributions`.

If `d1 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data1]` and `d2 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data2]`, you can do `RandomVariate[d1]` and `RandomVariate[d2]`, but, you get an error if you try `RandomVariate[d1*d2]`.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use `TransformedDistribution[d1 d2, {Distributed[d1, KernelMixtureDistribution[data1], Distributed[d2, KernelMixtureDistribution[data2]}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain a random sample of the product of two independent random variables, then you just need to use something like

```
n = 1000;
xy = RandomVariate[d1, n]*RandomVariate[d2, n];
```

If the observations are paired (each dataset having the exact same number of observations and observation k in one dataset is matched with observation k in the other dataset), then you can construct a bivariate distribution and then sample from that distribution:

```
d12 = KernelMixtureDistribution[Thread[{data1, data2}]]
x2 = #[[1]] #[[2]] & /@ RandomVariate[d12, n];
```

If the random variables are not independent and the two datasets are not matched, then you need to characterize the relationship between the two random variables.